# MariaDB: where firstname = 'André': returns rows with firstname = André and firstname = Andre

Tags: mariadb

I have the problem that I get too many rows back with a select statement. I limit the where part, but MariaDB ignores my comparison if the values in the column contain special characters.

In following example I inserted two rows in a table.

1. row contains "André" - last Character of this Name is "**é**" (U+00E9).
2. row contains "Andre" - last Character of this Name is "**e**" (U+0065).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `name_test` (`firstname` varchar(40) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48531 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

insert into name_test (firstname) values ('André');

insert into name_test (firstname) values ('Andre');

select * from name_test where firstname = 'André';

firstname
=========
André
Andre

select * from name_test where firstname = 'Andre';

firstname
=========
André
Andre

SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';

Variable_name                Value
==========================   =====
character_set_client         utf8
character_set_connection     utf8
character_set_database       utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem     binary
character_set_results        utf8
character_set_server         utf8mb4
character_set_system         utf8
character_sets_dir           /usr/share/mysql/charsets/



select 'Andrée' = 'Andree';

'Andrée' = 'Andree'
===================
1

SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_bin;

select 'Andrée' = 'Andree';

'Andrée' = 'Andree'
===================
0

select * from name_test where firstname = 'André';

firstname
=========
André
Andre

SHOW SESSION VARIABLES where variable_name like 'version%';


Variable_name                 Value
===========================   ================================
version                       10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
version_comment               Ubuntu 16.04
version_compile_machine       x86_64
version_compile_os            debian-linux-gnu
version_malloc_library        bundled jemalloc
```

why do I get two lines returned for the select statements instead of just one?

Is there a comparison operator other than "="?

Comment: Maybe **Select Distinct** ?

Comment: maybe.. but i select for "André" and i get "Andre" and "André". Andre is not equals to André

Comment: select distinct firstname from name_test where firstname = 'André'; --> Returns "André", select distinct firstname from name_test where firstname = 'Andre'; --> returns also "André". distinct returns always one row for more than one quals results. but "André" and "Andre" ist not qual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the character set/collation whether the accented characters are considered to be the same as the non-accented characters.

Changing the `collation_connection` value does not help as your column has it's own collation which is higher in collation precedence.

What you can do is to change the collation of the column or use `COLLATE`:

```
select * from name_test where firstname collate utf8mb4_bin = 'André' ;
```

Comment: Better would be to change the collation of the column -- if you want the same effect always.